# Assign a value to a var outside the cy.exec block

Tags: cypress

I am fairly new to cypress and this might be a novice question :)

I am trying to assign a value to a variable inside the cy.exec block and the value is right when I print it inside the block but it results in undefined when printed outside the block? Can anyone let me know how to proceed or any pointers on how to solve this?

My code:

```
    let cmd = `<a cmd>`
    var version: string
    cy.exec(cmd).then(result => {
        expect(result.stderr).to.be.empty
        ocpVersion = result.stdout
        cy.log('Inside exec')
        cy.log(version);
    })
    cy.log('Outside exec')
    cy.log(version);
```

Here logging the val inside the exec results a correct value but it returns undefined when logged outside exec.

Tried to debug but results in undefined value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 4):

Cypress provides aliases to store values from commands, to avoid problems such as this.

The alias variable is set with `.as()` and retrieved with `.get()`. In your example, use it as follows

```js
cy.exec(cmd).then(result => {
  expect(result.stderr).to.be.empty
  ocpVersion = result.stdout
  cy.log('Inside exec')
  cy.log(version);

  cy.wrap(ocpVersion).as('version')
})

// later
cy.get('@version').then(version => {
  cy.log('Outside exec')
  cy.log(version)
})
```

Reference in the docs [Variables and aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases)

Answer (score 1):

Fernando is correct about using an alias when dealing with asynchronous data, but a couple of other options are also available.

**Move the code into separate blocks**

Setting up asynchronous data is a `before()` block ensures that any asynchronous code like `exec()` are completed before the `it()` block is processed.

```js
let version;

before(() => {
  cy.exec(cmd).then(result => {
    version = result.stdout
  })
})

it('using version in a test', () => {
  cy.log(version)
  ...
})
```

**In the same block defer using the value with cy.then()**

Using `cy.then()` defers a synchronous command that need to use a value from an asynchronous call.

```js
it('using version in the same block', () => {
  let version;
  cy.exec(cmd).then(result => {
    version = result.stdout
  })

  // later
  cy.then(() => {      // defer 
    cy.log(version)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress maintains its own command queue, and enqueues new commands to that queue as it encounters them. This does not mean that those commands are run, but that Cypress is made aware that the commands will run once commands ahead of it in the queue are completed.

In *most* cases, this means that Cypress will just handle the asynchronous nature of their commands without any issue. But, with `cy.log()`, this has the side-effect of the enqueued command grabbing the value of what is in `cy.log()` at the moment it is enqueued, instead of when `cy.log()` is executed. A fairly straightforward example, similar to your issue:

```js
let printString = '--Beginning--';
cy.log(printString);
cy.then(() => {
  printString = '--Changed--';
});
cy.log(printString);
// Prints out:
// --Beginning--
// --Beginning--
```

To avoid this issue of enqueuing the `cy.log()` command *before* the value to be logged is set, we can use a `.then()` block (or another Cypress block) to prevent the value from being enqueued.

```js
    let cmd = `<a cmd>`
    var version: string
    cy.exec(cmd).then(result => {
        expect(result.stderr).to.be.empty
        ocpVersion = result.stdout
        cy.log('Inside exec')
        cy.log(version);
    }).then(() => {
      cy.log('Outside exec')
      cy.log(version);
    });
```